# Hyperlink for an image inside the div

Tags: html

I have multiple `div`'s used for an image slider which contains the image path as shown below.

```
<div data-src="images/slides/slideone.jpg">
            </div>
<div data-src="images/slides/slideone.jpg">
            </div>
<div data-src="images/slides/slideone.jpg">
            </div>
```

I want to add a hyperlink to each image but how can I do that...?

Comment: It depends on how your slider is built. The information you gave us is not enough, please set up a fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys thanks for all your suggestions. I solved the issue myself in very simple way.It looks like this:-

```
<div data-src="images/slides/slideone.jpg" data-link="yourlink">
            </div>
<div data-src="images/slides/slideone.jpg" data-link="yourlink">
            </div>
<div data-src="images/slides/slideone.jpg" data-link="yourlink">
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the slider is just static and will remain same then you can add the hyperlink as below:-

```
<a href="url">link text</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use JavaScript `location.href`  to add a hyperlink to div, in the `onclick` event

```
<div onlcick="location.href=url"></div>
```

Comment: Will check this one Nishad Nichoos

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways to do it depending on what frameworks/components you use. 
Here's a couple of simple methods that you may want to try:

**ALTERNATIVE 1**

```
<a href="PasteYourLinkHere"><div data-src="images/slides/slideone.jpg">
            </div></a>
<a href="PasteYourLinkHere"><div data-src="images/slides/slideone.jpg">
            </div></a>
<a href="PasteYourLinkHere"><div data-src="images/slides/slideone.jpg">
            </div></a>
```

**ALTERNATIVE 2**

```
<div data-src="images/slides/slideone.jpg" onclick="location.href='PasteYourLinkHere'">
            </div>
<a href="PasteYourLinkHere">This Text1</a>

<div data-src="images/slides/slideone.jpg" onclick="location.href='PasteYourLinkHere'">
            </div>
<a href="PasteYourLinkHere">This Text2</a>

<div data-src="images/slides/slideone.jpg" onclick="location.href='PasteYourLinkHere'">
            </div>
<a href="PasteYourLinkHere">This Text3</a>
```

Comment: Guys I just missed adding location.href('URL'), because thats the correct syntax when you use onClick event to change the browser location. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @user3004642   Please use the updated code in alternative 2, and when you provide url, you need to give the full length one ( for example **http:**//**www.google.com** , without asterisk ) I tested it, it works fine on my slider. If it still doesn't work for you, please share which component are you using for the slider.

Comment: @user3004642   Thank you for sharing the link my friend. I saw the slider (camera). There would definitely be a div or span or related tag enclosing the text below the image. You can use the above logic in that. If the issue still persists, please mail me at jaytechieguy@gmail.com. I am offering to fix this issue or any other problem that you may have, free of cost.

Comment: @user3004642   Have also updated the alternative2's code. Please have a look at it.

Comment: @Jay I tried updated alternative 2's code still not working... Check your mail, I have sent you the link and you can send me back the same if you find a solution for that...

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"><div class="cameraContent cameracurrent" style="display: block;"></div></a>
```

Comment: @user3004642 It's working, I just checked on your site. You have to use absolute path in your url

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this?

```
<a href="www.google.com">
    <div data-src="images/slides/slideone.jpg">
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: @user3004642, what is the address you want to link to?